# Name of this subgroup?

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, normal-subgroups

Let $G$ be a group and $H$ a subgroup of $G$. I was making some calculations and found this set:

$$K = \{h \in H~| ~ \forall g \in G, ghg^{-1} \in H\}$$

This is a subgroup of $G$ contained in $H$. Moreover, $K$ is normal in $G$, and is in some way the biggest normal subgroup of $G$ contained in $H$: if $N \unlhd G$ and $N \subseteq H$, then $N \subseteq K$. Is there a name for this structure?

Comment: @AlanWang yes, but $N_G(H) \neq K$: let $G$ be the dihedral group of the triangle, and $H$ be the subgroup of order $2$. Then, $K = \{1\}$ and $N_G(H) = H$. $K$ is somewhat a "dual" construction to the normal closure, I think.

Comment: Could the author of the downvote explain why he/she thinks the question is inappropriate? Maybe I can improve it.

Comment: @AlanWang dual in the sense of: while the normal closure is the "smallest" normal subgroup of $G$ containing $H$, $K$ is the "biggest" subgroup of $H$ that is normal in $G$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The subgroup you mean is the normal core of subgroup $H$.
It is defined by $$Core(H)=\bigcap_{x\in G}xHx^{-1}$$
It is the largest normal subgroup of $G$ which is contained in $H$.

Try to refer https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_(group_theory)

Comment: Thanks for the reference! The definition of the $p$-core is also very useful to me